# Replace @EnableSwagger2 after update to latest version

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

I migrated to latest `springfox-swagger2` version `2.10.0` but looks like `@EnableSwagger2` is deprecated.

What annotation should I use in order to enable Swagger into Spring Boot project? `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc`?

Comment: Don't use the `2.10.0` version it is not fully released
github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3336 ,github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3335

Comment: `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc` is also deprecated now!

Answer (score 33):

**@EnableSwagger2 was removed in swagger 2.10.x, but from 3.x.x it is there again.**

**@EnableSwagger2WebMvc is deprecated in 3.0.0+**

Funny but true :)

---

Optionally you can use following dependency with Spring 5 MVC

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and

- remove explicit dependencies on springfox-swagger2
- remove the @EnableSwagger2 annotations
- add the springfox-boot-starter dependency

see: https://github.com/springfox/springfox

Comment: It looks like `@EnableSwagger2` is working again in `springfox-swagger2 v.3.0.0`!

Comment: @EnableSwagger2 was not deprecated but suddenly removed in v2.10 :-(

Answer (score 5):

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2WebMvc
@Import({SpringDataRestConfiguration.class, BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class})
public class ApplicationSwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket schoolApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).
                select().
                apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.SampleProject")).
                paths(PathSelectors.any()).
                build();
    }
```

---

For the other case pertaining to spring security checks, you can make your securityconfiguration class to extend WebsecurityConfigurerAdapter and then you can implement below method -

```
 @Override public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      web.ignoring().antMatchers( "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/ui","/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html");
      
      }
```

This should help I guess

Comment: I have used the `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc` server started but I am unable to load swagger UI on `http://localhost:8090/swagger-ui.html`. I am getting `SpringSecurity` login page, after entering the valid credential still it is not loading, and asking for credential again and again

Comment: Error is `WARN  [2020-06-24T10:20:00.527+0530] servlet.PageNotFound ||${fallback:user}|No mapping for GET /swagger-ui.html`

Comment: I have `WebsecurityConfigurerAdapter ` in place as you mentioned

Comment: this had worked for me when I was getting kinda same errors

Comment: It's strange to me!!. After upgrade to latest version i.e `2.10.5`, it is giving me a same security dialog box

Comment: Anything else that I can try to get rid of this?

Comment: Found that this is an issue and latest release `2.10` is not ready to use
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3336
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3335