# The method apis(java.util.function.Predicate<springfox.documentation.RequestHandler>) in the type ApiSelectorBuilder is not applicable

Tags: spring-boot, maven, swagger

@Bean .api method is giving me below error. I have added Swagger config class with @Beans as usual.

```
The method apis(java.util.function.Predicate<springfox.documentation.RequestHandler>) in the type ApiSelectorBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (com.google.common.base.Predicate<springfox.documentation.RequestHandler>)
```

My Config class is below:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(                                            
                    "package com.sample.controller;"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
                                                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried these dependencies and the error did disappear.

Comment: This is correct. For springfox-boot-starter 3.0.0 version, you should use swagger-ui 3.0.0 only and not 2.9.2

Answer (score 25):

Remove the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

use the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That is not, what's mentioned in the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/62539860/7773582 and in the actual Github account https://github.com/springfox/springfox. But of course it is confusing; generally a more Spring integrated solution - when the Spring context is controlling what is possible - should do better. Therefore, ```springfox-boot-starter``` at least sounds more recommendable, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

This error happens if you add both "springfox-boot-starter" and "springfox-swagger-ui" dependency and if their versions are different.

Please note that if you are adding "springfox-boot-starter" then there is no need to add explicit "springfox-swagger-ui" dependency.

So just add the below and remove any "springfox-swagger-ui" dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who already have the right dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You may need to add `@EnabledWebMvc` if you don't have it already.

Springfox documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `package` and `;` semicolon to define `basePackage` for `.apis()`

```
RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.sample.controller")
```

And it seems you base package is `com.sample` then use that only

Full code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.sample.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
                                                
    }
}
```

Using dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still 'apis' method is giving the same error :  

The method apis(java.util.function.Predicate<springfox.documentation.RequestHandler>) in the type ApiSelectorBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (com.google.common.base.Predicate<springfox.documentation.RequestHandler>)

Comment: @Brinda you don't need to extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`

Comment: I have tried without  "WebMvcConfigurationSupport" too. But still that error exists. I don't know why that error exists for me.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem then after resolving those

Comment: @Eklavya: which Spring version and which dependencies (including swagger-ui) and also which Annotation for Configuration are you using? Can you paste your working example? Thank you!

Comment: @JochenGebsattel Dependencies added

Comment: see my comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63650789/7773582

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of all your io.springfox:springfox-* jars in your external libraries. There must be multiple versions getting mixed up. If you are using springfox-boot-started:3.0.0, then exclude other versions by doing exclusion. You don't need any other springfox dependency.
For me below fixed the issue -

```
      <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
      <artifactId>alpha-beta-api</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this error occured as the versions of my spring fox dependencies were different. Fixing the versions helped me solve this error. The below dependencies works well for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Already [answered by ashutosh5111](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67909452/5730279). Please upvote there or edit your answer and add something that differs from that answer.