# How to solve this error: 'apis(com.google.common.base.Predicate) can not be applied to (java.util.function.Predicate) SWAGGER UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

Hello everyone i'm trying to add Swagger UI to my backend project but i get this error in my SpringFoxConfig class:

```
'apis(com.google.common.base.Predicate<springfox.documentation.RequestHandler>)' in 'springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.ApiSelectorBuilder' cannot be applied to '(java.util.function.Predicate<springfox.documentation.RequestHandler>)'
```

My SpringFox Config Class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();

    }
}
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

This error comes from "apis(RequestHandlerSelectors)" and i don't know how to solve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194021/the-method-apisjava-util-function-predicatespringfox-documentation-requesthand?answertab=trending#tab-top men on that discussion did solve it

Answer (score 0):

you cannot mix Springfox 3.0.0 and 2.9.2 -> remove springfox-boot-starter