# rouble Enabling Swagger in Spring Boot: Need Guidance on @EnableSwagger2 Configuration

Tags: java, spring, swagger

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-19T12:45:13.371+01:00 ERROR 1404 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

What can be a problem if installed is:
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'

and after adding @EnableSwagger2 and opening the application, does the error appear as above?

Comment: Did you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64270801/12733532 ? It's for springfox 3